# What selichot do Ashkenazi Jews say?

Tags: selichot, elul

I am looking for a brief list (with some English, not Hebrew-only) of which selichot Ashkenazim say, on which days. 
If I understand correctly, most Modern Orthodox Ashkenazi Jews basically follow minhag Poland (Polin).
(So far I have only found lists for Sephardic or Chasidic minhagim.)

Comment: In the Ashkenazim Artscroll Selichot, they have the complete least.

Comment: "If I understand correctly, most Modern Orthodox Ashkenazi Jews basically follow minhag Poland (Polin)." That's not true in my experience. I think they mainly follow minhag Lithuania (Lita).

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear from the question itself, but since you tagged this [elul](/questions/tagged/elul), I assume you mean the selichos said during the last week of Elul? In that case, my [Artscroll Nusach Lita](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899068862.html) seems to be the volume you’re looking for.

The volume numbers the Selichos 1-100. In their Table of Contents (p. IX-XI) they have all the Selichos ordered by day, and they also have them listed in alphabetical order (p. XII-XIII). Do note that, especially on the longer days, many congregations skip one or more of the Selichos, but which one(s) varies from congregation to congregation. Also note that this list does not account for pieces which are said every day, like Machnisei Rachamim, so you may want to flip through each day to get a feel for the general proceedings.

Comment: Besides local shul *minhagim*, you may find small variations between Siddurim even for "common" Nusach Ashkenaz. Art Scroll is one of the few English-translated sources available for Selichot. There are others - I can't think of them, offhand.

Comment: It seems he wanted Polin not Lita

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh. I read that line as him saying he specifically *didn’t* want Polin. I’ll wait for him to respond before editing.

Comment: It can't hurt to include info about both for the next reader

Comment: Hi, I do want Polin; I'm an Ashkenazi Jew, so I'm under the impression that this would be the best fit for me. However, I recognize that the minhagim for which ones to recite vary very much! Interestingly, I have been told that many American Ashkenazi synagogues have been using minhag Lita? Not sure why, but it might simply be due to which compilations were readily available.  So that would be of interest, too. I am planning to buy the ArtScroll volume, but that might be over a week or two from now. Is there a list, or table of contents, that I could see?

Comment: I think that most chasidim use minhag polin